# send invites to facebook using openinviter

Tags: php, facebook, social-networking

I am working on openinviter to send invites to my facebook contacts list. When login with email and password with provider as `facebook` then I got the all contact details. But when I select one account and enter some message and click on "send invites" button then it showing error:

```
Email missing! Password missing!
```

I am using facebook : 1.2.9 version plugin of openinviter.

Comment: wow do you think anybody is going to send their info like that?

Comment: My Facebook plugin file facebook.plg.php file                          $_pluginInfo=array(
 'name'=>'Facebook',
 'version'=>'1.2.9',
 'description'=>"Get the contacts from a Facebook account",
 'base_version'=>'1.8.0',
 'type'=>'social',
 'check_url'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/causes/',
 'requirement'=>'email',
 'allowed_domains'=>false,
 );

Answer (score 1):

Try this fixed facebook plugin. It worked for me!
(You have to use the latest openinviter version)

```
<?php
/*Import Friends from Facebook
 * You can send message to your Friends Inbox
 */
$_pluginInfo=array(
    'name'=>'Facebook',
    'version'=>'1.3.0',
    'description'=>"Get the contacts from a Facebook account",
    'base_version'=>'1.8.4',
    'type'=>'social',
    'check_url'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/causes/',
    'requirement'=>'email',
    'allowed_domains'=>false,
    );
/**
 * FaceBook Plugin
 *
 * Imports user's contacts from FaceBook and sends
 * messages using FaceBook's internal system.
 *
 * @author OpenInviter
 * @version 1.0.8
 */
class facebook extends openinviter_base
    {
    private $login_ok=false;
    public $showContacts=true;
    public $internalError=false;
    protected $timeout=30;
    protected $userId;

    public $debug_array=array(
                'initial_get'=>'pass',
                'login_post'=>'javascript',
                'get_user_id'=>'profile.php?id=',
                'url_friends'=>'fb_dtsg:"',
                'message_elements'=>'fb_dtsg',
                'send_message'=>'"__ar":1',
                );

    /**
     * Login function
     *
     * Makes all the necessary requests to authenticate
     * the current user to the server.
     *
     * @param string $user The current user.
     * @param string $pass The password for the current user.
     * @return bool TRUE if the current user was authenticated successfully, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function login($user,$pass)
        {
        $this->resetDebugger();
        $this->service='facebook';
        $this->service_user=$user;
        $this->service_password=$pass;
        if (!$this->init()) return false;

        $res=$this->get("http://apps.facebook.com/causes/",true);
        if ($this->checkResponse("initial_get",$res)) $this->updateDebugBuffer('initial_get',"http://apps.facebook.com/causes/",'GET');
        else{
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('initial_get',"http://apps.facebook.com/causes/",'GET',false);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();
            return false;
            }
        $form_action="https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
        $post_elements=array('email'=>$user,
                             'pass'=>$pass,
                             'next'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/causes/home?_method=GET',
                             'return_session'=>0,
                             'req_perms'=>0,
                             'session_key_only'=>0,
                             'api_key'=>$this->getElementString($res,'name="api_key" value="','"'),
                             'version'=>'1.0',
                             );
        $res=$this->post($form_action,$post_elements,true,true);
        if ($this->checkResponse("login_post",$res)) $this->updateDebugBuffer('login_post',"{$form_action}",'POST',true,$post_elements);
        else{
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('login_post',"{$form_action}",'POST',false,$post_elements);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();
            return false;
            }

        $res=$this->get('http://facebook.com/',true);
        if ($this->checkResponse("get_user_id",$res)) $this->updateDebugBuffer('get_user_id',"http://facebook.com/",'GET');
        else{
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('get_user_id',"http://facebook.com/",'GET',false);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();
            return false;
            }


        //$this->userId=$this->getElementString($res,"{user:",',');  fixed by vikastyagi87@gmail.com


        $this->userId=$this->getElementString($res,"user:",',');
        if (empty($this->userId)) $this->login_ok=false;
        else $this->login_ok="http://www.facebook.com/ajax/social_graph/fetch.php?__a=1";
        return true;
        }

    /**
     * Get the current user's contacts
     *
     * Makes all the necesarry requests to import
     * the current user's contacts
     *
     * @return mixed The array if contacts if importing was successful, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function getMyContacts()
        {
        if (!$this->login_ok)
            {
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();
            return false;
            }
        else $url=$this->login_ok;
        $res=$this->get("http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={$this->userId}",true);
        if (strpos($res,'window.location.replace("')!==FALSE)
            {
            $url_redirect=stripslashes($this->getElementString($res,'window.location.replace("','"'));
            if (!empty($url_redirect)) $res=$this->get($url_redirect,true);
            }
        if ($this->checkResponse("url_friends",$res)) $this->updateDebugBuffer('url_friends',"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={$this->userId}&ref=profile",'GET');
        else{
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('url_friends',"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={$this->userId}&ref=profile",'GET',false);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();
            return false;
            }
        $postFormId=$this->getElementString($res,'name="post_form_id" value="','"');
        $fbDtsg=$this->getElementString($res,'fb_dtsg:"','"');
        $page=0;
        $form_action=$this->login_ok;
        $post_elements=array('edge_type'=>'browse',
                             'page'=>$page,
                             'limit'=>100,
                             'node_id'=>$this->userId,
                             'class'=>'FriendManager',
                             'post_form_id'=>$postFormId,
                             'fb_dtsg'=>$fbDtsg,
                             'post_form_id_source'=>'AsyncReques',
                            );
        $res=$this->post($form_action,$post_elements,true);
        $contacts=array();
        while(preg_match_all("#\{\"id\"\:(.+)\,\"title\"\:\"(.+)\"#U",$res,$matches))
            {
            $page++;
            $post_elements=array('edge_type'=>'browse',
                             'page'=>$page,
                             'limit'=>100,
                             'node_id'=>$this->userId,
                             'class'=>'FriendManager',
                             'post_form_id'=>$postFormId,
                             'fb_dtsg'=>$fbDtsg,
                             'post_form_id_source'=>'AsyncReques',
                            );
            $res=$this->post($form_action,$post_elements);
            if (!empty($matches[1]))
                foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$fbId)
                    if (!empty($matches[2][$key])) $contacts[$fbId]=$matches[2][$key];
            }
        return $contacts;
        }

    /**
     * Send message to contacts
     *
     * Sends a message to the contacts using
     * the service's inernal messaging system
     *
     * @param string $session_id The OpenInviter user's session ID
     * @param string $message The message being sent to your contacts
     * @param array $contacts An array of the contacts that will receive the message
     * @return mixed FALSE on failure.
     */
    /*public function sendMessage($session_id,$message,$contacts)
        {
        $res=$this->get('http://www.facebook.com/?sk=messages',true);
        if ($this->checkResponse("message_elements",$res)) $this->updateDebugBuffer('message_elements',"http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/?sk=messages",'GET');
        else{
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('message_elements',"http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/?sk=messages",'GET',false);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();
            return false;
            }
        $postFormId=$this->getElementString($res,'name="post_form_id" value="','"');
        $fbDtsg=$this->getElementString($res,'fb_dtsg:"','"');
        $form_action="http://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/async.php?__a=1";
        $post_elements=array();
        $countMessages=0;
        foreach($contacts as $fbId=>$name)
            {
            $countMessages++;
            if ($countMessages>$this->maxMessages) break;
            $post_elements=array( 'forward_msg'=>'',
                                  'body'=>$message['body'],
                                  'action'=>'send',
                                  'recipients[0]'=>$fbId,
                                  'force_sms'=>false,
                                  'post_form_id'=>$postFormId,
                                  'fb_dtsg'=>$fbDtsg,
                                  'post_form_id_source'=>'AsyncRequest'
                                  );
            $res=$this->post($form_action,$post_elements);
            if ($this->checkResponse("send_message",$res)) $this->updateDebugBuffer('send_message',"{$form_action}",'POST',true,$post_elements);
            else{
                $this->updateDebugBuffer('send_message',"{$form_action}",'POST',false,$post_elements);
                $this->debugRequest();
                $this->stopPlugin();
                return false;
                }
            sleep($this->messageDelay);
            if ($countMessages>$this->maxMessages) { $this->debugRequest();$this->resetDebugger();$this->stopPlugin();break; }
            }
        }*/
        public function sendMessage($session_id, $message, $contacts)
{
    $res = $this->get('http://www.facebook.com/?sk=messages&fb_noscript=1', true);
    $res = $this->get('http://www.facebook.com/?sk=inbox', true);

    if ($this->checkResponse("message_elements", $res))
        $this->updateDebugBuffer('message_elements', "http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/?sk=messages", 'GET');
    else {

        $this->updateDebugBuffer('message_elements', "http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/?sk=messages", 'GET', false);
        $this->debugRequest();
        $this->stopPlugin();
        return false;
    }
    $postFormId = $this->getElementString($res, 'name="post_form_id" value="', '"');
    $fbDtsg = $this->getElementString($res, 'fb_dtsg:"', '"');
    $form_action = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/async.php?__a=1";

    $form_action_gigaboxx = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/gigaboxx/endpoint/MessageComposerEndpoint.php?__a=1";

    $post_elements = array();
    $post_elements_gigaboxx = array();

    $countMessages = 0;

    foreach ($contacts as $fbId => $name) {
        $countMessages++;
        if ($countMessages > $this->maxMessages)
            break;
        $post_elements = array('forward_msg' => '',
            'body' => $message['body'],
            'action' => 'send',
            'recipients[0]' => $fbId,
            'force_sms' => false,
            'post_form_id' => $postFormId,
            'fb_dtsg' => $fbDtsg,
            'post_form_id_source' => 'AsyncRequest'
        );

        $post_elements_gigaboxx = array('_log_action' => 'send_new',
            'subject' => $message['subject'],
            'status' => $message['body'],
            'action' => 'send_new',
            'ids[0]' => $fbId,
            'post_form_id' => $postFormId,
            'fb_dtsg' => $fbDtsg,
            'post_form_id_source' => 'AsyncRequest',
            'target_id' => '0'
        );

        $res = $this->post($form_action, $post_elements);

        if ($this->checkResponse("send_message", $res))
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('send_message', "{$form_action}", 'POST', true, $post_elements);
        else {
            $res = $this->post($form_action_gigaboxx, $post_elements_gigaboxx);

            if ($this->checkResponse("send_message", $res)) {
                $this->updateDebugBuffer('send_message', "{$form_action_gigaboxx}", 'POST', true, $post_elements_gigaboxx);
            } else {
                $this->updateDebugBuffer('send_message', "{$form_action}", 'POST', false, $post_elements);
                $this->debugRequest();
                $this->stopPlugin();
                return false;
            }

            sleep($this->messageDelay);
            if ($countMessages > $this->maxMessages) {
                $this->debugRequest();
                $this->resetDebugger();
                $this->stopPlugin();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

    /**
     * Terminate session
     *
     * Terminates the current user's session,
     * debugs the request and reset's the internal
     * debudder.
     *
     * @return bool TRUE if the session was terminated successfully, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function logout()
        {
        if (!$this->checkSession()) return false;
        $res=$this->get("http://www.facebook.com/home.php",true);
        if (!empty($res)) $res=$this->get('http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?h='.html_entity_decode($this->getElementString($res,'http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?h=','"')));
        $this->debugRequest();
        $this->resetDebugger();
        $this->stopPlugin();
        return true;
        }
    }

?>
```